# Return File not returning pdf correctly MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently generating a pdf server-side using a pdf library.  When this has finished I then try and return this pdf to the user.

Everytime I try the PDF fails to open, or if I force it down as a download, downloads as a corrupted file.  If i type the physical address of the pdf into the browser it loads fine.

in my controller:

`return File(nfilePath, "application/pdf");`

In this instance nfilePath = ~/PdfStore/CurRep103323842.pdf

Im stumped at something this simple, any advice would be fantastic.  Thanks.

View that loads partial View

```
@model PrintShiftHandover.Models.ShiftHandOver

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShiftHandOver";
}

<div id="updateRegion">

@{Html.RenderAction("_ReportDetails");}

</div>
```

Partial View.

```
@model PrintShiftHandover.Models.MainReportDetail

@{
    Layout = string.Empty;
}

<div id="PartialView">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
```

............. a form here.

```
}
</div>
```

Controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _ReportDetails(Models.MainReportDetail model)
    {
                var getfile = new CreatePdf();
                var nfilePath = getfile.GetFile(model);


                return File(nfilePath, "application/pdf");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("",ex.Message);

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The pdf that is produced contains generated HTML from the main view, inside the div updateregion is where the pdf encoding is.

Comment: I bet if you open the downloaded file in a text editor it will show you an error message.

Comment: So what does the file look like in a text editor like Notepad?

Comment: Strange just opened it in notepad++ the encoding for the pdf is there, but at the top of it is html from my site.  Does it make any difference that this is done from a partialview controller?

Comment: If you look through the HTML, there will likely be an error message, can you find it?

Comment: Also, how are you calling the action method?

Comment: There's no error in my HTML, infact its the entire HTML of the main page that loads the partial page, inside the DIV where my partial would load is all of the %PDF-1.6 encoding.

Comment: Can you show the view code where the PDF is being sent?

Comment: updated question to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `@Html.RenderAction` which is essentially embedding the PDF file inside your output.

You need to replace that with a button/link instead that calls `@Html.ActionLink`. So replace the line that says:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("_ReportDetails");}
```

With:

```
@Html.ActionLink("_ReportDetails")
```

Alternatively, you could put a meta refresh tag or jQuery to force the file download to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I presumed whenever a file-action was returned it overrode whatever was going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "~" in your path.

Try:

```
//Convert to absolute path
nfilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(nfilePath);
return File(nfilePath, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: I had previously tried this, should have stated that in my answer, it does then ref the local file eg: c:\users\asde\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PdfProj\PdfProj\PdfStore\...  but still does the same thing.

Comment: Is there an exception? Is the downloaded file the same size as the original?

Comment: No exception in chrome, in IE Adobe says : File does not being with '%.PDF' and the file is 15kb bigger than the original.